# Moving Firestore security rule to custom function breaks rule

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a Firestore security rule that check that an user has the proper code to access another document.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Orgs/{orgID} {
      allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.OrgCode == resource.data.Code;
    }
  }
}
```

This works great. However, if I try to move this check into a custom function like so:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Orgs/{orgID} {
      allow read: if isPartOfOrg();
    }
  }
}
function isPartOfOrg(){
  return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.OrgCode == resource.data.Code;
}
```

Then I start to get permission errors. I haven't done anything but move the logic into a function, why is this not working?

Comment: The way you've scoped `isPartOfOrg` now means that it doesn't have access to `$(database)` as far as I can see. Ah, never mind... I see you've already found this out yourself. As an alternative to the solution already in your answer, you can also pass the parameters into the function call.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out while writing the question. The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#custom_functions) say that functions have access to variables and functions *from the scope in which they are defined* and not from where they are called.

So, move the function into the match block as so, and everything works again!

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Orgs/{orgID} {
      function isPartOfOrg(){
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.OrgCode == resource.data.Code;
      }
      allow read: if isPartOfOrg();
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps others who run into this issue!