# Firestore.rules custom function not evaluating as intended

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following document hierarchy:
/organizations/{orgId}/classes/{classId}/students/{studentId}

The idea is the class document has a teacherUid field, which currently stores the Uid of the teacher assigned to the class.  Only a teacher or admin should be able to read/create/edit students in the class. *Note that I'm only testing reading by the teacher, ran into this hurdle, after which I'll apply the same rule to the create/update permission.

I have the following firestore.rules:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /organizations/{orgId} {
      allow read: if isAdmin();
      allow create, update: if isAdmin();

      match /classes/{classId} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
        allow create, update: if isAdmin();

        match /students/{studentId} {
          allow read: if isAdmin() || belongsToCurrentClass();
          allow create, update: if isAdmin();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


function isAdmin() {
  // Removed for security.  isAdmin routine currently works correctly
}

function belongsToCurrentClass() {
  // returns true if the authenticated user is the teacher of the requested class
  return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/organizations/$(orgId)/classes/$(classId)).data.teacherUid == request.auth.uid;
}
```

This does not appear to be working.  While it correctly allows admins to read/create/edit it does not allow reading by the authenticated user with the same request.auth.uid as the teacherUid value stored in the parent class document.

I've tested this using both the online firebase console firestore simulator as well as running mocha unit tests hitting the local firestore emulator.

I can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

Here are the relevant portions of my test.js document:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const TEST_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID = 'test-firestore-rules-project';

const firebase = require('@firebase/testing');

const authTeacher = {
  uid: 'testTeacher1',
};

const authAdmin = {
  // Removed for security
};

before(async () => {
  // The above was from the codelab.  Commenting out the below since we aren't testing rules at this moment.
  const rulesContent = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../firestore.rules'));
  await firebase.loadFirestoreRules({
    projectId: TEST_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    rules: rulesContent,
  });
});

after(() => {
  firebase.apps().forEach(app => app.delete());
});

...

describe('Classes/Students/* rules', () => {
  const testClassPath = 'organizations/testOrg/classes/testClass';
  const testStudentPath = testClassPath + '/students/testStudent';
  const newStudentPath = testClassPath + '/students/newStudent';
  const testOtherClassPath = 'organizations/testOrg/classes/testClass';
  const testOtherStudentPath = testOtherClassPath + '/students/testOtherStudent';
  const newOtherStudentPath = testOtherClassPath + '/students/newOtherStudent';

  const dbUnauth = firebase
    .initializeTestApp({
      projectId: TEST_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    })
    .firestore();

  const dbTeacher = firebase
    .initializeTestApp({
      projectId: TEST_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
      auth: authTeacher,
    })
    .firestore();

  const dbAdmin = firebase
    .initializeTestApp({
      projectId: TEST_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
      auth: authAdmin,
    })
    .firestore();

  before(async () => {
    const admin = firebase
      .initializeAdminApp({
        projectId: TEST_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
      })
      .firestore();

    // Create Class - for testing classes that belong to the authenticated user
    await admin.doc(testClassPath).set({
      teacherUid: authTeacher.uid,
    });

    // Create Student
    await admin.doc(testStudentPath).set({
      name: 'John Smith',
    });

    // Create Other Class - for testing classes that belong to other users
    await admin.doc(testOtherClassPath).set({
      teacherUid: 'someOtherTeacherUid',
    });

    // Create Other Student
    await admin.doc(testOtherStudentPath).set({
      name: 'Cave Johnson',
    });
  });

  after(() => {
    // Clear data from the emulator
    firebase.clearFirestoreData({ projectId: TEST_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID });
  });

  it('Unauthenticated users cannot access students', async () => {
    await firebase.assertFails(dbUnauth.doc(testStudentPath).get());
  });

  it('Unauthenticated users cannot create students', async () => {
    await firebase.assertFails(
      dbUnauth.doc(newStudentPath).set({
        name: 'Jane Doe',
      })
    );
  });

  it('Non-admin users can read students', async () => {
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(dbTeacher.doc(testStudentPath).get());
  });

  it('Non-admin users cannot read students from another user', async () => {
    await firebase.assertFails(dbTeacher.doc(testOtherStudentPath).get());
  });

  it('Non-admin users can edit students', async () => {
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(
      dbTeacher.doc(testStudentPath).set({
        anotherProperty: 'Some Value',
      })
    );
  });

  it('Non-admin users cannot edit students from another user', async () => {
    await firebase.assertFails(
      dbTeacher.doc(testOtherStudentPath).set({
        anotherProperty: 'Some Value',
      })
    );
  });

  it('Non-admin users can create students', async () => {
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(
      dbTeacher.doc(newStudentPath).set({
        name: 'Jane Doe',
      })
    );
  });

  it('Non-admin users cannot create students in a class they do not belong to', async () => {
    await firebase.assertFails(
      dbTeacher.doc(testOtherStudentPath).set({
        name: 'Jane Doe',
      })
    );
  });

  it('Non-admin users cannot delete students', async () => {
    await firebase.assertFails(dbTeacher.doc(testStudentPath).delete());
  });

  it('Admin users can read students', async () => {
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(dbAdmin.doc(testStudentPath).get());
  });

  it('Admin users can create students', async () => {
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(
      dbAdmin.doc(newStudentPath).set({
        name: 'Jane Doe',
      })
    );
  });

  it('Admin users can edit students', async () => {
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(
      dbAdmin.doc(testStudentPath).set({
        anotherProperty: 'Some Value',
      })
    );
  });

  it('Admin users cannot delete students', async () => {
    await firebase.assertFails(dbAdmin.doc(testStudentPath).delete());
  });
});
```

Here is the error output when running the unit tests:

```
PS C:\Local\Personal\Angular Projects\TSI\functions> npm test

> functions@ test C:\Local\Personal\Angular Projects\TSI\functions
> mocha



  Organization rules
    √ Unauthenticated users cannot read organizations (48ms)
    √ Unauthenticated users cannot create orgs organizations
    √ Unauthenticated users cannot delete organizations
    √ Non-admin users cannot read organizations (45ms)
    √ Non-admin users cannot edit organizations
    √ Non-admin users cannot create organizations
    √ Non-admin users cannot delete organizations
    √ Admin users can read organizations (47ms)
    √ Admin users can create organizations
    √ Admin users can edit organizations
    √ Admin users cannot delete organizations

  Classes rules
    √ Unauthenticated users cannot access classes
    √ Unauthenticated users cannot create classes
    √ Unauthenticated users cannot delete classes
    √ Non-admin users can read classes (38ms)
    √ Non-admin users cannot edit classes
    √ Non-admin users cannot create classes
    √ Non-admin users cannot delete classes
    √ Admin users can read classes
    √ Admin users can create classes
    √ Admin users can edit classes
    √ Admin users cannot delete classes

  Classes/Students/* rules
    √ Unauthenticated users cannot access students
    √ Unauthenticated users cannot create students
    1) Non-admin users can read students
    √ Non-admin users cannot read students from another user
    2) Non-admin users can edit students
    √ Non-admin users cannot edit students from another user
    3) Non-admin users can create students
    √ Non-admin users cannot create students in a class they do not belong to
    √ Non-admin users cannot delete students
    √ Admin users can read students
    √ Admin users can create students
    √ Admin users can edit students
    √ Admin users cannot delete students


  32 passing (3s)
  3 failing

  1) Classes/Students/* rules
       Non-admin users can read students:
     FirebaseError: 
Null value error. for 'get' @ L15
      at new FirestoreError ...
  2) Classes/Students/* rules
       Non-admin users can edit students:
     FirebaseError: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: 
false for 'update' @ L16
      at new FirestoreError ...
  3) Classes/Students/* rules
     FirebaseError: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: 
false for 'create' @ L16
      at new FirestoreError ...

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Comment: FYI, I'd probably answer this in 10 seconds if I could just run the rule evaluation in a debug session.  If you have any idea how to inspect the values when the rules engine evaluates a request I'd love to here it.  So as not to ask two questions in the same SO post I've asked for debug advice here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58796514/how-to-debug-firestore-rules-variables-and-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh. :) Found the issue.  Posting my answer here in case this trips anyone else up.

Per the [Firestore custom function documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#custom_functions) the function needs to be declared within the scope of the variables it's using, or the variables can be passed as arguments.

Similar to the same issue on SO here:
[Moving Firestore security rule to custom function breaks rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496675/moving-firestore-security-rule-to-custom-function-breaks-rule)

Either one of the two following options works:

**Option 1 - Declaring within the scope of the variables:**

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /organizations/{orgId} {
      allow read: if isAdmin();
      allow create, update: if isAdmin();

      match /classes/{classId} {
        function belongsToCurrentClass() {
          // retuns true if the authenticated user is the teacher of the requested class
          return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/organizations/$(orgId)/classes/$(classId)).data.teacherUid == request.auth.uid;
        }

        allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
        allow create, update: if isAdmin();

        match /students/{studentId} {
          allow read: if isAdmin() || belongsToCurrentClass();
          allow create, update: if isAdmin() || belongsToCurrentClass();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function isAdmin() {
  // Removed for security.
}
```

**Option 2 - Passing variables as arguments:**

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /organizations/{orgId} {
      allow read: if isAdmin();
      allow create, update: if isAdmin();

      match /classes/{classId} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
        allow create, update: if isAdmin();

        match /students/{studentId} {
          allow read: if isAdmin() || belongsToCurrentClass();
          allow create, update: if isAdmin() || belongsToCurrentClass(database, orgId, classId);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function isAdmin() {
  // Removed for security.
}

function belongsToCurrentClass(database, orgId, classId) {
  // returns true if the authenticated user is the teacher of the requested class
  return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/organizations/$(orgId)/classes/$(classId)).data.teacherUid == request.auth.uid;
}
```

I personally went for Option 1.  While I don't like declaring functions within my code passing all the arguments was pretty ugly as well, and the function wouldn't even be called outside of that scope, so it made more sense to declare it there.